# vb6 - GetData from winsocket when State = closing

Tags: tcp, vb6, winsock

I am building an HTTP client in Visual Basic 6, that sends data to server with the header:

```
Connection: Close
```

Wich forces the web server to close connection right after all data has been sent. I have this code to receive the data:

```
Private Sub rqt_DataArrival(Index As Integer, ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
On Error GoTo errorHandler
Dim buff As String
If bytesTotal > 0 Then
    rqt(Index).GetData buff
    WSDataBuffer(Index) = WSDataBuffer(Index) & buff
End If

Exit Sub
errorHandler:
MsgBox "error in state: " & rqt(Index).State & ". Bytes left: " & bytesTotal
End Sub
```

The problem is that 1 out of 5 times or so, I get an error **'40006' :
Wrong protocol or connection state for the requested transaction or request.** in the line:

```
rqt(Index).GetData buff
```

So I placed that error handler to see what was going on and the problem is that the .State = 8 (closing state). But there is still data to be received, because bytesTotal is 195.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you, from the **client**, closing the connection after sending?...or is the **server** actually closing the connection after receiving?

Comment: The server (apache), closes the connection right after everything is sent, because of the header `connection: close` tells him so (the alternative would be using `connection: keep-alive` but I need it to be closed by the server.

Comment: IIRC... some HTTP servers are sort of nasty in the way they close the connection and just forcibly break it using `RST` abort instead of following the proper `FIN` handshake.  This is probably related to hacks meant to defeat certain denial of service attack types.

Comment: I have translated all the code from visual basic 6 to visual studio C# and now it works perfectly. So I guess it might have been an issue of visual basic 6.

Comment: Or your VB6 logic had a bug.  I guess we'll never know.